# How to count on two columns of group by items in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have generated two columns(origin and destination) out of 'n' number of columns. Now I want to generate count for these two columns combination. I am not able to get the result. I am getting error as,  ERROR 1070: Could not resolve Count using imports:
Below is my script,

```
mydata = load '/Projects/Flightdata/1987/Rawdata' using PigStorage(',') as (year:int, month:int, dom:int, dow:int, deptime:long, crsdeptime:long, arrtime:long, crsarrtime:long, uniqcarcode:chararray, flightnum:long, tailnum:chararray, actelaptime:long, crselaptime:long, airtime:long, arrdeltime:long, depdeltime:long, origcode:chararray, destcode:chararray, dist:long, taxintime:long, taxiouttime:long, flightcancl:int, canclcode:chararray, diverted:int, carrierdel:long, weatherdel:long, nasdel:long, securitydel:long, lateaircraftdel:long);

Step2 = foreach mydata generate origcode, destcode;
grpby = group Step2 by (origcode, destcode) ;
step3 = foreach grpby generate group.origcode as source,  group.destcode as destination, Count(step2);
```

here I want to generate count for each combination of origin and destination.
Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Pig documentation about case sensitivity](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#case-sensitivity)

> The names of Pig Latin functions are case sensitive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried with the same case but its still not working.

Comment: error is,    ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports:

Comment: Fred can you please guide for one more step. Now I got the count of origin and destination combination. Now i am trying to get the Maximum count for whole records. 1) One way is to sort them in descending order and then store only top record.  2) I wanted to achieve this by using script. I am doing group all on all the 3 columns and trying to generate Max value on this. But it is failing,     step5 = group step3 all;
maxval = foreach step5 generate 
FLATTEN(step5.(source, destination, routcount)),  MAX(step5.routcount);